# Trying to extract text from specific tag that contains other tags. BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, tags

I have the following html

```
    <div class="1" style="">
         text0
         <span class="2">text1</span>
      <div class="3" title="something" name="something1">
         text2
         <span class="small">text3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and i'm trying to extract text0 with BeautifulSoup.

But

```
div = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"1", "style":"").text.strip()
```

or

```
div = soup.find("div", {"class":"1", "style":"").get_text()
```

is not working. Any ideas????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What happens?

First at all there is a typo in your code, a closing `}` is missing, so all of your selections will come up with an error.

`find_all()` would not work, cause you can not get the text directly from `result set` you have to iterate over it.

To get all of the text for one element your line should be changed to:

```
 soup.find("div", {"class":"1", "style":""}).text.strip()
```

#### How to get only text0?

You can use `stripped_strings`and pick the first element from result set:

```
list(soup.find("div", {"class":"1", "style":""}).stripped_strings)[0]
```

Alternativ you can iterate `contents` and break if next tag appers:

```
for e in soup.find("div", {"class":"1", "style":""}).contents:
    if not e.name:
        print(e.text.strip())
        break
```